# A query concerning $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of the sequence $\langle 1-\cos(1/n)\rangle$.

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Since the sequence $\langle a_n\rangle=\langle 1-\cos(1/n)\rangle$ is convergent, so $\limsup a_n=\liminf a_n=\lim a_n =0.$ At first, I calculated the limit superior and the limit inferior of $\langle a_n\rangle$ using the traditional method which is by determining the two sequences: $b_n=\sup\{a_n,a_{n+1},\ldots\}$ and $c_n=\inf\{a_n,a_{n+1},\ldots\}$ followed by taking their $\inf$ and $\sup,$ respectively. As expected, I obtained $\limsup a_n=0=\liminf a_n.$

However, we also know that if $L$ is the set of all limit points of $\langle a_n\rangle,$ then $\limsup a_n=\sup L$ and $\liminf a_n =\inf L$ (which is equivalent to saying that the limit superior is the greatest subsequential limit and the limit inferior is the least subsequential limit). In the present case, $L=[0,1-\cos 1].$ So, $\limsup a_n=1-\cos 1$ and $\liminf a_n=0.$ The results obtained here are absurd. I must be missing something obvious! It seems that $L$ should be the singleton set $\{0\}.$ But, $a_n=1-\cos(\frac1n)=2\sin^2(\frac1{2n})\in(0,2\sin^2(1/2))=(0,1-\cos 1).$ This implies $L=[0,1-\cos 1],$ as I mentioned before.

Please help me see where I went wrong...

Comment: $0$ is the only limit point of the sequence. How did you get $L=[0,1-\cos 1]$?

Comment: @geetha290krm In my opinion, if we consider the term $a_1=1-\cos 1=2\sin^2(1/2),$ then any $\delta$-nbd of $a_1$ contains infinite number of elements of the set $\{2\sin^2(\frac1{2n})\,:\,n\in\mathbb N\}.$ The same goes for the other terms of the sequence as well. That was why I took $L=[0,1-\cos 1].$ Just like the set of limit points of the sequence $\langle \cos n\rangle$ is $[-1,1].$ Please correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: $2\sin^{2}(\frac 1 {2n})$ is strictly smaller than  $2\sin^{2}(\frac 1 {4})$,   for every $n>2$ so any limit point of the sequence cannot exceed $2\sin^{2}(\frac 1 {4}) (<2\sin^{2}(\frac 1 {2}))$. Hence,  $2\sin^{2}(\frac 1 {2})$ cannot be a limit point.

Comment: Agreed, as $n$ increases $a_n$ decreases. But, how can we be so sure that for any fixed $k(\ge2)\in\mathbb N,\,2\sin^2(\frac1{2k})$ can't be a limit point of $\langle a_n\rangle$ ?

Comment: Consider the open interval from $2\sin^{2} (\frac 1  {2k+2})$ to $2\sin^{2} (\frac 1  {2k-2})$ . This interval has only finite number of points of the sequence because it does not contain $2\sin^{2} (\frac 1  {2n})$ whenever  $n >k+1$.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Understood. Thank you so much ma'am/sir (sorry, I am not able to determine your gender from your name!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the sequence starts with $1-\cos 1$, this number has nothing to do with limit points. The first few terms of  a sequence have no effect on the limit points. The only limit point of this sequence is $0$.